# Should a big QByteArray be heap allocated?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, stack, heap-memory

On Windows on a Qt C++ application, I'm reading image data from an instrument. The instrument driver gives me a pointer to the data and basic image information:

- width 1400
- height 1200
- size 3360000
- depth 14 bits

In other words, an image file is almost 3MB.

I'm storing that on a [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html), on that stack.

Is that 3MB too big for the stack? Should that be on the heap?

Answer (score 3):

QByteArray does its own heap allocation (in the constructor or whenever it needs to grow). So you can declare a QByteArray of any size on the stack. When the variable goes out of scope, the destructor will release the memory.

The C++ standard library equivalent is `std::vector<uint8_t>` or `std::vector<char>`.